# How to capture a repeating optional value

Tags: regex

All my attempts to capture everything before the ,"" only return the last occurrence. I have the following couple of source strings examples.

```
{"rec_timestamp": "2016-12-25T11:43:38.763-0700","151521": "-18.788","151515": "25","151522": "2.804","151520": "3506","151523": "-18.4","11124": "NO_DEFECT|","151516": "0","151510": "ALCLFA2BA314","151518": "3.28","151519": "24.398438","": "","": "","": "","": ""}
{"rec_timestamp": "2016-12-25T11:43:38.763-0700","151521": "-18.788","151515": "25","151522": "2.804","151520": "3506","151523": "-18.4","11124": "NO_DEFECT|","151516": "0","151510": "ALCLFA2BA314","151518": "3.28","151519": "24.398438"}
```

So for the first record I would up to ..."24.398438" returned into $1 (everything before ,"") and the second example return the entire row as is (,'' is optional)?

I tried:

```
(^.*)(,""*?)
(^.*)(,"".*)
```

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/LNHYOY/2

Comment: The input strings look like valid JSON. Is there any reason you cannot use a JSON-decoding function to restore the encoded data structure and fetch the values from it?

Answer (score 0):

With the language you use, regular expression is greedy by default : the `.*` part wants to match as long as possible. You can make regular expression ungreedy (it would want to match as few characters as possible), by replacing `.*` with `.*?`.

Here, your substring is delimited by the start of the line at the beginning, and the characters `,""` or the character `}` at the end of the line. With something like this, you get a standardized match (omitting the `}` charcter)

```
^(.+?)(,"".*|\}$)
```

If you don't need to capture the second part, you may use an assertion instead.

```
^(.+?)(?=,""|\}$)
```